# Plunker Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: reactjs, cloudflare, plunker

I am using Plunker to produce my React Example.

The React Libraries are included by "Find and external libraries" provided by Plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/U3soXYgU2ek8j2IA22WE?p=preview

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="react@*" data-semver="16.1.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/cjs/react.development.js"></script>
    <script data-require="react@*" data-semver="16.1.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/cjs/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script data-require="react-jsx@*" data-semver="0.13.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script data-require="react-jsx@*" data-semver="0.13.1" src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.jsx**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (<h1>Hello World!</h1>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>, 
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

In the console, It throws the below exception

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at VM26837 script.js:32
(anonymous) @ script.js:32
```

However, This example works if I tried another react libraries such as that provided by unpkg.com.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0-alpha.13/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0-alpha.13/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Then, how can i import the module? Could I import React from 'react'?

Comment: import React from 'react'. It also throws exception. Require is not defined.

Comment: The React v16 libs didn't work for me. This ones worked:
    <script data-require="react@0.12.2" data-semver="0.12.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/react.js"></script>
    <script data-require="react-jsx@*" data-semver="0.12.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks Troglo. I also find that the old version work fine but not the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `type="text/jsx"` is missing. Add `type="text/jsx"` to your script as `<script type="text/jsx" src="script.jsx"></script>` and try. And use `umd` build for development. See the working code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="script.jsx"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**cjs(commonjs2):** User will use this format in a `build tool`, it excludes all modules in `node_modules` folder from bundled files.

**umd:** User will use this format `directly in browser`, all 3rd-party packages will be bundled within.

Comment: Tested with your suggest. It still throw exception of "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
"

Comment: @BenCheng - See the updated answer. Hope that will helps you!

Comment: same exception as before

Comment: What is the difference between cjs and umd? The default library provided by plunger is cjs.